How to design this table using Springer template
I was initially working with the MDPI template, and so I explain confusion matrix using the table below, and works fine as I wanted it:
\documentclass[applsci]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\caption{Confusion Matrix}
    \label{tab:confusion_matrix}
    \begin{tabular}{llccc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{Predicated Class}} & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \textit{Positive} & \textit{Negative} & \textit{Class Support} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{ \textbf{Actual Class}}& \textit{Positive} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{True Positive (TP) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{False Nagetive (FN)}  & \textbf{P} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    & \textit{Negative} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{False Positive (FP) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{True Negative (TN)}  &  \textbf{N} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{document}

Output:

Now, I switched to write the manuscript using Springer's Latex template, and wanted to have the exact output. However, I could manage to have it work. It outputs the table below instead:

How do I get the same output as in MDPI?
Edit:
Document class and code used with Springer Nature template.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,smallcondensed]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\caption{Confusion Matrix}
    \label{tab:confusion_matrix}
    \begin{tabular}{llccc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{Predicted Class}} & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \textit{Positive} & \textit{Negative} & \textit{Class Support} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{ \textbf{Actual Class}}& \textit{Positive} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{True Positive (TP) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{False Nagetive (FN)}  & \textbf{P} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    & \textit{Negative} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{False Positive (FP) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{True Negative (TN)}  &  \textbf{N} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Edit 2
I can confirm this WME works fine (in overleaf) as seen here.

There are several "Springer templates" for LaTeX documents. Please be more specific as to which one of the possible templates you need to employ.

Springer Nature LaTeX template, link in the question, available here: https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

Please confirm that your document starts with \documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}.

@Mico question edited with MWE and document class used in the Springer Nature template, which gives the output in the screenshot.

In order to confirm that your examle is indeed working (the W part of MWE), create a new folder on your computer, create a new .tex file and copy the example code there. If you can compile it, everything's fine. However, that's not what you'll find for your code snippet. Please make it a compilable document. Avoid unnecessary inclusions and provide all files that you absolutely need to include.

@schtandard thank you for pointing out to that. I missed the \begin{document}..\end part (corrected now), and I can confirm this works fine on overleaf. The only thing I could not add is the sn-jnl.cls  document class of Springer template, but I pointed to the source (url) in the question.

@Mico sorry, I see what you mean now. Question edited and can confirm MWE works just fine in overleaf.

The Springer LaTeX template class file (sn-jnl.cls) redefines the way \cline works. Instead, it produces content similar to what is provided by the booktabs package. If you want to achieve your original layout, you can either bring back the way \cline works (from latex.ltx), or use something else... like \fbox:

\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,smallcondensed]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 

% Redefine \cline to match original definition in LaTeX kernel.
\makeatletter
\def\cline#1{\@cline#1\@nil}
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\templena}% Temporary length
\newlength{\templenb}% Temporary length

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  %\caption{Confusion Matrix}
  %\label{tab:confusion_matrix}
  \begin{tabular}{ l l c c c }
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Predicted Class} & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \itshape Positive & \itshape Negative & \itshape Class Support \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Actual Class} & \itshape Positive & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{True Positive (TP)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{False Negative (FN)} & \bfseries P \\
    \cline{3-4}
    & \itshape Negative & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{False Positive (FP)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{True Negative (TN)} & \bfseries N \\
    \cline{3-4}
  \end{tabular}
  
  \bigskip
  
  \settowidth{\templena}{~False Positive (FP)~}% Set maximum box/column width for Positive
  \settowidth{\templenb}{~False Negative (FN)~}% Set maximum box/column width for Negative
  \begin{tabular}{ l l c @{} c c }
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Predicted Class} & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \itshape Positive & \itshape Negative & \itshape Class Support \\
    & \itshape Positive & \fbox{\makebox[\templena]{True Positive (TP)}} & \hspace{-\fboxrule}\fbox{~False Negative (FN)~} & \bfseries P \\[\dimexpr\baselineskip-\fboxrule]
    \raisebox{0.5\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule}[0pt][0pt]{\bfseries Actual Class} & \itshape Negative & \fbox{~False Positive (FP)~} & \hspace{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\makebox[\templenb]{True Negative (TN)}} & \bfseries N \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}

In the above two examples, the first uses the original definition of \cline, while the second uses \fboxes and forgoes the need for multirow. The first option - redefining \cline - is likely too much as it goes against the publisher definitions. The second option is simpler and package independent, therefore preferred.

elegant solution, thank you. Accepted answer.

If, in your MWE, I load the package nicematrix and replace the environment {tabular} by the environment {NiceTabular} (provided by nicematrix), I have directly the expected output.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,smallcondensed]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\caption{Confusion Matrix}
    \label{tab:confusion_matrix}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{llccc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{Predicted Class}} & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \textit{Positive} & \textit{Negative} & \textit{Class Support} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{ \textbf{Actual Class}}& \textit{Positive} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{True Positive (TP) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{False Nagetive (FN)}  & \textbf{P} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    & \textit{Negative} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{False Positive (FP) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{True Negative (TN)}  &  \textbf{N} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


The reason is that nicematrix, in its environment (such as {NiceTabular} redefines the command \cline because the standard command \cline protrudes in the cell below and that nicematrix wants to provide a command \cline without that behavior.
Of course, nicematrix provides many other features.

Anyway, I managed to find a workaround that's just fine.
% edited to provide MWE
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,smallcondensed]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\caption{Confusion Matrix}
    \label{tab:confusion_matrix}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} % Adjust column spacing
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % Adjust row height
    \begin{tabular}{llp{3cm}p{3cm}c} % Adjust column widths
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Predicted Class}} & \\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \textit{Positive} & \textit{Negative} & \textit{Class Support} \\
        \cmidrule(r){3-4}
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Actual Class}} & \textit{Positive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{True Positive (TP)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{False Negative (FN)} & \textbf{P} \\
        \cmidrule(r){3-4}
        & \textit{Negative} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{False Positive (FP)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{True Negative (TN)} & \textbf{N} \\
        \cmidrule(r){3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Output:


Please make your code fragment compilable. Which document class you use?
